# Iterate over a list of dfs, applying a fn to same col within each df

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

have a large df that I have split into a list of dfs by level of a specific col. I'm trying to iterate over said list of dfs, accessing the same col within each df, while applying the get_nrc_sentiment() fn to all the rows of text data, within aforementioned col, in each df.

```r
library(syuzhet)

# create example df
df <- data.frame("a"=c(1:3, 1, 1), 
"b"=c("bad", "angry", "joy", "happy", "unhappy"))
df

df_split <- split(df, df$a)  
df_split # split df by a into list of dfs    

# iterate over col data in each df within 
# list of dfs and apply sentiment function
for(i in 1:length(df_split)){
df2 <- lapply(as.vector(df_split[[i]]$b), function(x) get_nrc_sentiment(x))
}   
# for some reason only works for last df within list of dfs
df2  

# desired output, but for each df col within list
df3 <- get_nrc_sentiment(as.vector(df_split[[1]]$b))
df3

# output of df
  a       b
1 1     bad
2 2   angry
3 3     joy
4 1   happy
5 1 unhappy

# output of df_split
$`1`
  a       b
1 1     bad
4 1   happy
5 1 unhappy

$`2`
  a     b
2 2 angry

$`3`
  a   b
3 3 joy

# output of code within for loop
[[1]]
  anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive
1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     0        0        1

# output of df3, desired output example for each df within list
  anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive
1     1            0       1    1   0       1        0     0        1        0
2     0            1       0    0   1       0        0     1        0        1
3     1            0       1    0   0
```

As you can hopefully see, this only seems to work on the last df within the list of dfs as opposed to all of the dfs within the list of dfs. I may be going at it the wrong way with a for loop, I also tried lapply within lapply but have no other ideas for how to access a col within each df of a list of dfs. Greatly appreciate the help and hope the examples I provided are sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `lapply` inside a loop as `lapply` will apply the same function to each element of the list. Alternatively, you can use `purrr::map`.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("syuzhet")

# create example df
df <- data.frame(
  "a" = c(1:3, 1, 1),
  "b" = c("bad", "angry", "joy", "happy", "unhappy"),
  # Don't make `b` a factor
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# split df by a into list of dfs
df_split <- split(df, df$a)

lapply(
  df_split,
  function(x) get_nrc_sentiment(x$b)
)
#> $`1`
#>   anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative
#> 1     1            0       1    1   0       1        0     0        1
#> 2     0            1       0    0   1       0        0     1        0
#> 3     1            0       1    0   0       1        0     0        1
#>   positive
#> 1        0
#> 2        1
#> 3        0
#> 
#> $`2`
#>   anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative
#> 1     1            0       1    0   0       0        0     0        1
#>   positive
#> 1        0
#> 
#> $`3`
#>   anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative
#> 1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     0        0
#>   positive
#> 1        1

df_split %>%
  map(~ get_nrc_sentiment(.$b))
#> $`1`
#>   anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative
#> 1     1            0       1    1   0       1        0     0        1
#> 2     0            1       0    0   1       0        0     1        0
#> 3     1            0       1    0   0       1        0     0        1
#>   positive
#> 1        0
#> 2        1
#> 3        0
#> 
#> $`2`
#>   anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative
#> 1     1            0       1    0   0       0        0     0        1
#>   positive
#> 1        0
#> 
#> $`3`
#>   anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative
#> 1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     0        0
#>   positive
#> 1        1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the great response! Achieved exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code fully but I provided below a example on how to apply the function to each df and put them all into a list. I hope it helps.

```
res <- list() # empty list to put into final result


for (i in seq(length(list_a))) {
  l <- as.data.frame(list_a[[i]]) # convert every df in list to normal df
  l = l$b # put your sentiment function here 
  res[[i]]=l  # add every df result to list of df, not just last one 
  print(res)

}
```